# Use of pragma directive in C

Tags: c, pragma

I am trying to learn C language using Visual Studio 2019 and tried the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1();
# pragma startup f1
int main()
{
    printf("Hey");
    return 0;
}
void f1()
{
    printf("Hello1\n");

}
```

I was expecting the output to be 
Hello1
Hey

but I am getting
Hey

Looking forward to inputs on what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Did you compile it with MSVC or gcc? Don't compile it with gcc, obviously.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314039/is-pragma-directive-compiler-dependent

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I am using Visual Studio 2019, so I believe it would be Microsoft compiler in the background. Not sure which compiler it chooses as I just click the run button to check the output.

Comment: If you're learning C, forget `#pragma`, you don't need pragma directives for the moment. Pragmas are an advanced topic.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-pragmas?view=msvc-160

Comment: Microsoft C compiler does not know about the startut pragma and silently ignores it. Pragmas are only intended to request special processing to *specific compilers*. Do not use them if you are learning C.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The other way around. `# pragma startup` is known by MSVC and Embarcadero and probably a few others, but not by gcc.

Comment: @Lundin: AFAIK, Visual Studio has no support for gcc, but it can use Clang as a back end. The libraries are still Microsoft specific, but at least the language part is closer to the standard...

Comment: @Lundin: `#pragma startup` may have been supported by older versions but it is not referenced in current Microsoft documentation. And I can confirm that MSVC2019(v142) does ignore it (as do the CLang backend).

Comment: @SergeBallesta So which compiler _is_ it supposed to be used for? Embarcadero only?

Comment: @Alok Which friendly manual told you to use `# pragma startup`, more precisely?

Comment: A book named "Let us C" talks about pragma startup and I was trying it out to learn more about it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just tested the pragma in older MSVC through WINE/Godbolt and none of them seem to recognize the pragma indeed. So it is neither for MSVC nor gcc, nor clang, apparently.

Comment: @Alok Ah, from what I remember, that book has a big red anti-recommendation from various C gurus using this site, including Antii Happila who took some time to read the thing, see revision 43 of this book list: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/562377/revisions. Antii is a well-known contributor to this site and knows what he is talking about. While Yashwant Kanetkar is just some random dude who apparently shouldn't be writing books.

Comment: @Alok: then my advice is that you should look for a better book... Beginners should never try to use pragmas.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and inputs.

Comment: @Alok throw away that book and get a book from that list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/562377#562377

Answer (score 2):

The example you are using will only work in Borland/Embarcadero compilers, something the author of that book should have clarified for you. This pragma will not work with MCVS, gcc and clang compilers.

For gcc-like compilers, you can use this compiler extension instead:

```
void f1 (void); 

void __attribute__((constructor)) f1 (void) 
{ 
  puts("Hello world"); 
}
```

---

Regarding *Let us C*, it turns out you are reading a harmful book written by an incompetent author. From SO's C book recommendation list:

> Also do not use the book [Let Us C](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/9387284492/) (16<sup>th</sup> Edition, 2017) by Yashwant Kanetkar. Many people view it as an outdated book that teaches Turbo C and has lots of obsolete, misleading and incorrect material. For example, page 137 discusses the expected output from `printf("%d %d %d\n", a, ++a, a++)` and does not categorize it as [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) as it should. It also consistently promotes unportable and buggy coding practices, such as using `gets`, `%[\n]s` in `scanf`, storing return value of `getchar` in a variable of type `char` or using `fflush` on `stdin`.

This book has been read and reviewed by at least two well-known and respected C gurus on this site and the claims above show that this book is not just outdated - it is spectacularly bad. Counting yours sincerely as well, there's now at least three 100k+ rep C tag users of SO giving a big fat anti-recommendation against this book.

You need to stop reading this harmful book immediately. Please show this post to your teacher.